What is a word for a college course + time?
A course can be Econ 101. The course can be taken at 1pm, or 5pm.
Is there a word that means "the Econ 101 course at 5pm"?
Edit: Removed bit about students.

"the Econ 101 course at 5pm with Stan and Nan". Is there in your language? why "with", anyway. Stan and Nan's 5pm Econ 101. as opposed to some other course they take.

On 2nd thought, the "with" part is irrelevant. Removed from question.

class could refer to session, subject, or students https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/class

A session is a general term for a specified block of time devoted to a particular activity. You could refer to the two class times as the "1pm session" and "5pm session". Worth noting that this somewhat implies a singular time and doesn't necessarily imply a repeating event, but it would be fairly clear in the context of an ongoing class that the "5pm session" refers to a daily or weekly time.

When a course has multiple classes taking the same course but at different times or with different instructors, these are usually called sections.
From Merriam-Webster,

11a: one of the classes formed by dividing the students taking a course
b: one of the discussion groups into which a conference or organization is divided

These sections might be referred to by time or by instructor's name. I can't imagine how anybody could reference their classmates in a single word though. Maybe you didn't mean to include Stan and Nan in your "is there a word" though. You might say "I'm taking the Wednesday 5pm section of Econ 101, along with Stan and Nan."

"Sectionmates"?
